# Vue - composition API Array inside reactive is not updating in the DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have an Array of posts inside reactive() and I want it to be updated onMounted.

How can I do this?

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<q-card>
  <board-item-list :items="items" v-if="items.length" />
  <board-empty v-else />
</q-card>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
import { reactive, onMounted } from "vue";
import { posts } from "./fake-data.js";
export default {
  setup() {
    let items = reactive([]);
    ...
    onMounted(() => {
      // to fill the items with posts.
      items.values = posts; // I tried this not working
      items = posts; //I tried this not working
      console.log(items);
    });
    ...
    return {
      ...
      items,
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `ref` instead of `reactive` or define `items` as nested field in a reactive state like :

```
import { reactive, onMounted } from "vue";
import { posts } from "./fake-data.js";
export default {
  setup() {
    let state= reactive({items:[]});
    ...
    onMounted(() => {
     
      state.items = posts; 
      console.log(state.items);
    });
    ...
    return {
      ...
      state,
    };
  },
};
```

in template :

```
<q-card>
  <board-item-list :items="state.items" v-if="state.items.length" />
  <board-empty v-else />
</q-card>
```

if you want to get rid of `state` in the template you could use `toRefs`:

```
import { reactive, onMounted,toRefs } from "vue";
import { posts } from "./fake-data.js";
export default {
  setup() {
    let state= reactive({items:[]});
    ...
    onMounted(() => {
     
      state.items = posts; 
      console.log(state.items);
    });
    ...
    return {
      ...toRefs(state),//you should keep the 3 dots
    };
  },
};
```